# Getting BitcoinLib Error = "One or more required parameters, as defined in CoinParameters, were not found in the configuration file!"

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, bitcoinlib

I'm using [BitcoinLib](https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib) in my ASP.NET Core (v2) Web Api project. However, whenever I try to instantiate the service:

```
        var bitcoinService = new BitcoinLib.Services.Coins.Bitcoin
                .BitcoinService(appSettings.BitcoinSettings.ServerUrl,
                                appSettings.BitcoinSettings.Username,
                                appSettings.BitcoinSettings.Password,
                                appSettings.BitcoinSettings.WalletPassword);
```

I get the error:

> One or more required parameters, as defined in CoinParameters, were not found in the configuration file!

I verified that the values that are being passed in are not null and correct, I've even added the settings to my `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="RpcRequestTimeoutInSeconds" value="60" />

    <add key="Bitcoin_DaemonUrl" value="http://localhost:18332" />
    <add key="Bitcoin_DaemonUrl_Testnet" value="http://localhost:18332" />
    <add key="Bitcoin_WalletPassword" value="X" />
    <add key="Bitcoin_RpcUsername" value="X" />
    <add key="Bitcoin_RpcPassword" value="X" />
  </appSettings>
...
```

Nothing works... do I need to fork this thing and remove that `IgnoreConfigFiles` check or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Can you try with the latest version? Currently it's the v1.3.4 that was just released a few hours ago.

Comment: That actually did fix the overload problem, but the problem now is that it is not `.NET Core compatible`... so I still have to use my fork...

Comment: We'll be releasing a .NET Standard version this month. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception showing was a misdirection... the actual problem was with `rpcRequestTimeoutInSeconds`. The library needs to have an overload like this:

```
BitcoinService(string daemonUrl, string rpcUsername, string rpcPassword, string walletPassword, short rpcRequestTimeoutInSeconds)
```

It looks like the `NuGet` package is missing it? As I can see it in the code...

More info here:
https://github.com/GeorgeKimionis/BitcoinLib/issues/42

I did create a `.NET Core` compatible one here:
https://github.com/SaganMarketing/BitcoinLib

You can get a package here:
https://www.myget.org/feed/saganmarketing/package/nuget/BitcoinLib